# Error multiplying numbers in the trillions

Tags: c++, eclipse, boost, int, long-integer

I am trying to perform a calculation to get from the total microseconds of the current time back to the current time in HHMMSSFFF format by performing a series of calculations. However, when I try to subtract the hours*3600000000 from the total number of microseconds, the returned value is not correct (it is off by one order of magnitude and the number itself is wrong. Does anyone know how to fix this? I tried using long long int and long double but these both outputted the same value. I have copied below the code and the resulting output in the console.

The times are stored in a vector as data comes in (aka a time stamp) which is why there is a temp_counter. I am using time_duration in the boost::posix_time library.

```
long double total = cur_time.at(temp_counter).total_microseconds();

cout << total << endl;

int hours = total/(3600000000);
cout << hours << endl;
long long int temp = hours*3600000000;
cout << std::setprecision(20) << temp << endl;
total = total - temp;
cout << total << endl;
```

Output:

35465976558

9

2335228928

33130747630

By my calculations, temp should actually be 32400000000 and the new total should be 3065976558.

Comment: On which operating system?

Comment: I believe that hours*3600000000 causes overflow. What is size of long long int? Even if 64-bit maybe not enough. Even if it is big enough, you need to cast hours to it and not use as int.

Comment: Linux, Ubuntu to be exact

Comment: Try `hours*3600000000LL`.

Comment: So what would be the maximum value I can use that wouldn't cause overflow? Because I know a long long in can hold a value up to 2^64

Comment: It's overflowing because you perform the multiplication *before* converting to long long. Basically the same issue as `double x = 1/2`.

Answer (score 1):

The calculation is:

35465976558/
3600000000 = 9,851660155 cast to int equals 9

9 * 3600000000 = ... and here the crap hits the fan because 3600000000 cannot be put into a 32 bit int and doesn't seem to be cast correctly to long long, hence you should cast the right hand side to long long int.

But as you are getting a long double in the first assignment: Why not using long double (or at least double) all the way and avoid the casting horror?

Comment: Ya I get what you're saying. The problem is that I have to put it back into a time_duration which only accepts ints, which is why I was using ints the entire time. I just multiplied hours by 36000000 instead, and subtracted it from temp/100 and then multiplied the difference by 100 and it worked to bypass the overflow